# Using Filters in R google_analytics

Tags: r, google-analytics

Im trying to do the following

```
google_analytics(my_id,  
                   date_range = c("2018-08-25", "2019-12-31"), 
                   metrics = c("ga:pageviews"
                               ,"ga:uniquePageviews"

                   )
                   ,segments = seg_obj

                   ,dimensions = c("date"
                                   #,"ga:channelGrouping"
                                   #,"ga:deviceCategory";
                                   ,"ga:pagePath"
                                   #,"ga:segment"
                   )
                   , anti_sample = TRUE
                   ,filters  = "ga::pagePath=@x",max = 100000)
```

But it returns an error saying

> API returned: Invalid value 'ga::pagePath-@x' for filters parameter.

Also tried using 2 equal signs and also with filtersExpression but same resulting in error.

Tried to follow another question asked at link:

[GoogleAnalyticsR api - FilterExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799283/googleanalyticsr-api-filterexpression)

Any idea why this is happening and how i can resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Stupid error. I was using `ga::pagePath` when it should be `ga:pagePath`

Comment: For the dimensions, you do not have to specify the "ga:" suffix at all, so `c("date", "pagePath")` will also work.